# heroku php codeigniter procfile unable to open webboot.sh

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, heroku

heroku is unable to open webboot.sh which is in the same directory as my Procfile. Any ideas why?

Procfile:

```
web: sh webboot.sh
```

webboot.sh:

```
sed -i 's/Listen 80/Listen '$PORT'/' /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf
sed -i 's/^DocumentRoot/# DocumentRoot/' /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf
sed -i 's/^ServerLimit 1/ServerLimit 8/' /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf
sed -i 's/^MaxClients 1/MaxClients 8/' /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf

for var in `env|cut -f1 -d=`; do
  echo "PassEnv $var" >> /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf;
done
echo "Include /app/www/conf/httpd/*.conf" >> /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf
touch /app/apache/logs/error_log
touch /app/apache/logs/access_log
tail -F /app/apache/logs/error_log &
tail -F /app/apache/logs/access_log &
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/php/ext
export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/app/www
echo "Launching apache"
exec /app/apache/bin/httpd -DNO_DETACH
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it still matters for you, but if your Procfile and webboot.sh are in your document root, your Procfile should call:

```
web:    sh www/webboot.sh
```

As far as I understand it your Pocfile will be called in /app, while your default document root will be /app/www.